# How can I tell if my wifi router is max out?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, bandwidth

I have a netgear r6300 wifi router for our office, and we have 43 devices connected to it. We're experiencing some problems with the router kicking people off. I suspect we may have too many devices connected on it and we're running out of bandwidth, but I don't know how to properly diagnose that. I can see on the statistics page Tx on the 5ghz endpoint is 557,389 B/s. The 2.4 ghz endpoint is 507,481 B/s. But without any historical record it's hard to pinpoint when spikes have happened.  I don't have a NAS, but I do use dropbox and gdrive which large video files could be going into.  So bandwidth usage could spike more.

I've thought about going and buying a switch to drop hard lines for some people as our office is wired for that, but I could just buy another wifi router to balance out the load.  I will say that the 2ghz endpoint experienced this problem a while back and I moved people that could to the 5ghz endpoint to balancing things out.  That worked until now and now 5g is crowded and we're seeing people getting booted.

I thought that the 2ghz could have interference with other wifi networks around us, but 5ghz was alone.  No one else has a 5ghz network to interfere with us.

I'm looking for either empirical steps to diagnose usage problems (including 3rd party software) or rule of thumb on how many users a router could support. I have looked for 3rd party firmware (DD-WRT, tomato, etc) that may give me more features to diagnose this on the router, but I haven't found anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Netgear traditionally has a 4096 simultaneous session limit on their home-grade stuff.  With that many devices, you can max that out pretty easily I would think.

Try the [latest firmware](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/R6300V2/R6300v2_V1.0.2.72_1.0.46.zip) from Netgear (V1.0.2.72), as there's unconfirmed (by me) reports that a later firmware bumps that limit to 65K sessions.  If that's not helping, look into buying a business-grade device instead.

References:

- [First Look: NETGEAR R6300 WiFi Router-802.11ac Dual Band Gigabit - Routing Perf, Wireless Perf-11ac](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/31772-first-look-netgear-r6300-wifi-router-80211ac-dual-band-gigabit?start=1)

> The R6300 has higher routing throughput, if that's important to you.
>   But NETGEAR has kept to its traditional 4,096 limit on simultaneous
>   sessions.

- Netgear Forums: [Maximum Number of Simultaneous/Active Sessions](http://forum1.netgear.com/showthread.php?t=78559)

Comment: You must be quoting specs for a wired router. 802.11 has a hard limit of 2007 simultaneous clients on a single BSS (read: as single AP, but beware that in this sense, a simultaneous dual-band AP is really two APs (two BSSes) in one.) 2007 (x2) is still a lot more than OP's 43 devices, but it still seems wrong to quote stats that only apply to wired devices.

Comment: @Spiff While I don't disagree with what you're saying, I quoted stuff that is directly referring to the Router model the user stated.  Including that forum link, in which a Netgear rep seems to confirm that there's a _session_-limit (not a 'device' limit).  I would think those session are split amongst all connection types as well (wired or wireless).  But I am well aware you're a WiFi savant, so if you've got any ideas, PLEASE post an answer. :)

Comment: We are far under those limits.  We are a company with 50 people.  Even with phones, tablets, laptops of 50 people we couldn't exhaust 2K or 4K sessions.